# how to connect obiee to postgres db?

Tags: database, oracle, postgresql, oracle12c, obiee

Need to connect Postgres database to OBIEE 12c.
Is there any official documentation?
Is it possible not to use third-party drivers, such as from Cdata?
Which driver do I need JDBC or ODBC?
OBIEE deployed on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OBI can analyze anything you want via ODBC. You need an ODBC driver. JDBC will only be available when you switch to future Oracle Analytics Server versions.